# Highcharts Treemap color selected point

Tags: select, highcharts, state, treemap

I need to use the select state in a Treemap to change the color of the selected area (it works well for other charts like pie charts, bubble charts...). But the state seems to not be taken into account.
The demo is here : https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/0xuqvrg3/

I tried to use the settings described in the documentation (I tried "color" and "marker/fillColor") :

```
plotOptions: {  
  series: {    
    allowPointSelect: true,      
    states: {       
      hover: {
            color: "#ff0000",
            marker: {
              fillColor: "#ff0000"          
            }
      },        
      select: {
          color: "#0000ff",
          marker: {
             fillColor: "#0000ff"
          }         
      }
  },
```

But no success... Any idea to achieve that please ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This doesn't seem to be supported out of the box. Did you ran across this post? https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=43127

Comment: It works great with the added function. Thanks !